# Upload multi images to firestore using flutter and get it's download URLs and save all of URLs to firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, async-await, firebase-storage

I have a form that have images to upload , when the user try to press on "Submit" button i'm trying to upload list of images to firestore and get all of its URLs and then submit a form to "x" collection in firebase but the writing on "x" collocation done before upload the images and get it's URLs.

I thinks the problem with (async,await).

Appreciate to help me.

```
List<File> imagePaths= new List() ;
List<String> imageURL= new List() ;

Future<FirebaseUser> getUser() async {
    return await _auth.currentUser();
}

Future<void> uploadPic(File _image) async {

    String fileName = basename(_image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = 
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(Random().nextInt(10000).toString()+fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
    var downloadURL = await(await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    var url =downloadURL.toString();
    imageURL.add(url); // imageURL is a global list that suppose to contain images URLs
    print("\n ---------------------------\n downloadURL :"+ url);
    print("\n ---------------------------\n imageURL :"+ imageURL.toString());

  }


Submit(BuildContext context)   {
    //imagePaths is list of file 
    imagePaths.add(Front_image);
    imagePaths.add(Back_image);

    imagePaths.forEach((x)  => {
       uploadPic(x)
    });


    getUser().then((user) {

      crudObj.addNew({
        'uid': user.uid,
        'name': name,
        'images':imageURL,
      }).then((result) {
        Navigator.pop(context);

      }).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
      });
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your Submit only once your upload task is complete. I would recommend implementing something like this:

```
Stream uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(File image, String fullPath) {
  final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fullPath);
  StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(image);

  return task.events;
}
```

And then listen to this Stream and only then submit:

```
uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(
  image, 'path/imagename.jpg'
).listen((data) async {
  StorageTaskEvent event = data;
  if (data.type == StorageTaskEventType.success) {
    String downloadUrl = await event.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    await Submit(title, imageUrl: downloadUrl);
    return true;
  }
  if (data.type == StorageTaskEventType.failure) return false;
});
```

Please take note that I did not re-write your code, I am sharing a possible implementation.

Comment: But I have multi images not one image

Comment: Then you need to run the code for each image, what is the issue?

Comment: In you solution i will subit the form as number of images. I need to submit the form once all of the images url ready